# How do you create a taxonomy in Orchard Core?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcore

I'm trying to create a Taxonomy in Orchard Core.

Ive read these docs, but David Hayden's blog post is missing exactly where you create a new Taxonomy. There must be a button do to this somewhere? (OR how to create a Taxonomy Content Type.)

https://www.davidhayden.me/blog/taxonomies-in-orchard-core-cms
https://docs.orchardcore.net/en/dev/docs/reference/modules/Taxonomies/

The Taxonomy 'feature' is enabled and I've created a 'Content Type' for the items, but no idea how to create a Taxonomy to assign these to.

I'm using the version on the DEV channel. (Currently rc1-12174)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taxonomies are content items. Go under Content / Content Items, then expand the "New" drop-down on the top-right and select "Taxonomy".

Comment: For those arriving, this is true however there could be some issues if you disable and reactivate the feature. (Or change the types the feature is expecting.) https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/issues/5655